# How to handle the else case of a ternary operator?

Tags: powershell

I have a incoming string in a certain format that I want to parse into a `PsCustomObject`. I dont have the means to predetermine the strings format. The string is something like this:

```
Home - Apples
https://apples.com

Home - Bananas
https://bananas.com

Home - Mangos
https://managos.com
```

And I want to format it into an object like so:

```
Title                        URL
-------                  -----------
Home - Apples      https://apples.com
Home - Bananas     https://bananas.com       
Home - Mangos      https://managos.com
```

I have tried a few things but they have all failed. I thought this would be trivial but apprently not so. Here is the closest I have gotton:

```
$MySites =
@'

Home - Apples
https://apples.com

Home - Bananas
https://bananas.com

Home - Mangos
https://managos.com

'@


$Obj = $MySites  -split "\n" -notmatch "^$" | ForEach-Object {
            [pscustomobject]@{
                Title   = $_ -notmatch "^https?:/?/?" ? $_ :
                URL     = $_ -match "^https?:/?/?" ? $_ :
            }
        }
    }
```

The above fails to even load into PowerShell. I got the following:

```
ParserError:
Line |
  12 |                  Title   = $_ -notmatch "^https?:/?/?" ? $_ :
     |                                                              ~
     | You must provide a value expression following the ':' operator.
```

I also tried `Title   = $_ -notmatch "^https?:/?/?" ? $_ : (return)` but I got the old "command not recognized" error:

```
The term 'return' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

Perhaps I am being dumb by using a ternary operator here, I am still fairly early into PowerShell, so I run out of ideas. How would you handle it?

I am also really keen in how to handle the else condition of a ternary operator, for example when I only want to only specify the if condition.

Thanks for any help

Edit1:
@Santiago, I tried your solution. Ony my end the `Uri` property ends up getting nested.I tried to figure where this origniates from but no luck. Here is my output of your code:

---

```
Title         Uri
-----         ---
Home - Apples {https://apples.com, , Home - Bananas, https://bananas.com…}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible that you might do it by splitting on those empty lines and then splitting again in the new-line characters, this is probably simpler than what you were approaching. No ternary needed also.

```
$MySites = @'
Home - Apples
https://apples.com

Home - Bananas
https://bananas.com

Home - Mangos
https://managos.com
'@

$MySites -split '(?m)^\s*$' | ForEach-Object {
    $title, $uri = $_.Trim() -split '\r?\n'

    [pscustomobject]@{
        Title = $title
        Uri   = $uri
    }
}
```

Regarding your question about [ternary operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#ternary-operator--if-true--if-false), this is how the syntax looks:

```bash
0..10 | ForEach-Object {
    # <condition> ? <if true> : <if false>
    $_ -gt 5 ? "$_ is greater than 5" : "$_ is lower than or equal to 5"
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks allot Santiago for your asnwer, and @mklement0 for the help.